# Spark Scala Unit test getting failed

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, hive

I am getting this below error while running the test for maven. I have HADOOP_HOME, hadoop.dll file , everything is set up in my local machine and path , environmental variables for my machine. Previously it was running fine. While I had to clone a different repository I started getting this error. Can anyone help me with this.

```
  org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.createDirectoryWithMode0(Ljava/lang/String;I)V;
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.withClient(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:108)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.databaseExists(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:196)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.externalCatalog$lzycompute(SharedState.scala:114)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.externalCatalog(SharedState.scala:102)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.externalCatalog(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:39)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.catalog$lzycompute(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:54)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.catalog(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:52)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder$$anon$1.<init>(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:69)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.analyzer(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:69)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.BaseSessionStateBuilder$$anonfun$build$2.apply(BaseSessionStateBuilder.scala:293)
  ...
  Cause: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.createDirectoryWithMode0(Ljava/lang/String;I)V
  at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.createDirectoryWithMode0(Native Method)
  at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.createDirectoryWithMode(NativeIO.java:524)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkOneDirWithMode(RawLocalFileSystem.java:465)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkdirsWithOptionalPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:518)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkdirs(RawLocalFileSystem.java:496)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.mkdirs(FilterFileSystem.java:316)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.createPath(SessionState.java:694)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.createSessionDirs(SessionState.java:613)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:547)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.newState(HiveClientImpl.scala:180)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you haven´t set the **library path**. Try to set the java.library.path java property with the folder where the ***hadoop.dll*** is located. If you execute your tests with maven you can set the property of the forked jvm that executes the tests with the **argLine** option:

```
mvn -DargLine="-Djava.library.path=[hadoop_dll_dir_path]"
```